# Strange Conflict between Apache, CURL and MySQL outputs?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, curl

I have very strange situation...

**Platform**: Win7, apache24, mysqld 5.6.x, php5.5.10

**query1** = "SELECT abc FROM table1 WHERE id=123 " (result give me about 200 rows)

**query2** = "SELECT abc FROM table2 WHERE id=555 " (result give me about 200 rows)

**In short, PHP code looks like this:**

**step1**. I'm using my own DB Wrapper and I make query1 to table1. In result I receive multiple rows from table1. I save it to php array using while loop.

**step2**. next I make curl requests to 3rd party API using foreach loop. Request are very simple and working fine at 150 other places in my script.

**What is wrong?**

Scripts are working fine.. but only one time after apache start/restart.

**What going next?**

- When I try reload page for test it again - curl response is empty. http_code for curl request is 200, but request is empty.
- After apache restart script working again - one time.
- Without step1 curl working fine all time.
- And one more... when I try query2 (similar to query1) but for different table (query2 to table2) script works fine everytime (after refreshing too).

**What i tried:**

- testing different headers in curl,
- curl options like curlopt_fresh_connect and all f... possible configurations.
- dumping printing all possible variables...
- googling, binging, yandexing....
- after step1 I tired connect to different websites than API, google, websites without ssl etc - result is the same. Crash after 1 run.

Browser cache is not a problem, API limits are fine.

I wasted for it 9 hours and I dont know what is wrong:)
If you have any ideas - please share with me.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling different version of apache?

Comment: @Roshan I tried run code on 2 different VMs. After your reply I tired with latest apache version. No good result.

Comment: Or maybe there's a conflict on your DB wrapper. You made all of that?

Comment: full error checking and display is on?

Comment: @Roshan I dont think that is a problem on DB wrapper side. Query working well in described file and in other files.

Comment: @tim, yes + logging all errors + debug_backtrace for all functions + logging every action(update, insert, select, changes, script steps) to database. Also I follow queries in real time at /server-status

Comment: php5.5.10 you know that's no longer supported and should not bee used right?

Comment: @tim, yes but I think that the problem is not related to php version. I have alot of code which works great with this php version. I use that code for development "localhost" projects which I never interact with people. For temporary I moved SQL query to separate file and I will connect to thiis file using curl (ex localhost/file.php?ids=1,2,3,4,5. But it is not a solution for above problem. I need to know why it crashing. If you have any more ideas please write, i will describe final solution in this topic.

Comment: We cannot debug your problem without access to logs/errors/data. So just 2 ideas: a white page is usually a result of a php error, so make sure you [display errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424) (and add them to your question). If this doesn't help to narrow it down: if it's a database problem and replacing q1 by q2 solves it, I'd suspect either the specific data (maybe you don't escape some character properly?) or a transaction lock (e.g. your code wants to update table1, but q1 locks table1 (but q2 doesn't)). I'd probably start debugging by replacing q1 with the hardcoded resultset.